# SiteCore - Order Manager Performance Issue

Tags: performance, sitecore, sitecore7

We are using SiteCore's SES module for an ecommerce implementation and the order manager module seems slow i.e. when orders are loaded once we log in, the time take to complete this task is quite a bit.

Is there a way for us to pin point which part of the process needs to be tuned?

We are little concerned as we are planning to process about 500 orders a day and wondering if the Order Manager can handle such a volume at all!

Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: Is SES a bottleneck for your scenario?

Comment: Yes, to a certain extent. The bottleneck is more on the Order Manager end rather than the whole SES module.